# Understanding the defintion of dual operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I'm reading a book about Functional Analysis, and now I've reached to the part about dual operators.

I'm having some difficulties understanding the following definition -

[image]

Why $A^*$ is $Y^*\rightarrow X^*$?
We know that $\phi \in Y^*$, i.e., $\phi:Y\rightarrow Y$ and bounded. So the image of $\phi(Ax)$ should be in $Y^*$, shouldn't it?

How come it's in $X^*$?

($X^*$ is reffered here as the space of all bounded linear functionals on $X$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $\phi$ is a functional, so it is $\phi:Y\to\mathbb{C}$.

Next, what is $A^*$? It takes a functional $\phi\in Y^*$ and returns a function $A^*(\phi)=f$ which is defined by $f(x)=\phi(A(x))$. If we take a vector $x\in X$ then $A(x)\in Y$ and then $\phi(A(x))\in\mathbb{C}$. So $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$. Then of course you need to check that $f$ is linear and bounded, but that's easy. So $f\in X^*$.

Comment: i have some confusion between your use of "functional" and "function", a functional is alias for a function from vector to scalar, f is also a function from vector to scalar (from X to C), while their domain is different (phi is on Y and f is on X) they're both functions from vector space to scalar space, no? I do not understand your use of different terms here.

Comment: @Sheed A functional is not any function from a vector space to the field, it also has to be linear. $f$ is indeed a functional, but linearity has to be checked. This is really easy, but still. I guess that's why I called it a function here, not a functional. (That's my guess. Not that I remember much what I was writing $5$ years ago)